# How to avoid loading all the beans of the other Batch job if not running it

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to the `Spring Batch` wanted to understand how we can avoid the below issue. In my project, we are using `AppCommonConfig` where we've listed all the batch files to be called and using Spring Boot. When I run the `AAA` batch job, it loads all the beans of other batch job as well which I think is not the correct approach.

How we can avoid or tweak the below code ?

I only wanted to load those beans which are part of my currently running batch job.

**AppCommonConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test1.test2")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:appconfig.properties")
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/Q.xml", "classpath:META-INF/R.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/ABC.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/XYZ.xml",
        "classpath*:META-INF/AAA.xml", "classpath*:META-INF/YYY.xml",
        "classpath*:META-INF/KKK.xml", "classpath:META-INF/BBB.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/CCC.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/DDD.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/EEE.xml" ,
        ............
        ...............
        ...............
        ...................
        "classpath:META-INF/ZZZ.xml"})
public class AppCommonConfig {
    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring profiles: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles.

In your case, you can have one profile per job. When you run your app with a specific profile, only the beans of that profile will be loaded.

As a side note, It seems not natural to me to have a `AppCommonConfig` class where you import all the batch job definitions. I would put only common beans in that class (data source, transaction manager, etc) and create a separate class for each job (in which case, you won't probably need to use profiles as beans are separated by design).

Comment: Thanks. It make sense to use Profile to distinguish between the jobs and not to allow to initialized other beans. Can you please guide. How can we tweak the "AppCommonConfig" class to use profiles? Your code snippet will help.